# How can I use multiple databases in a sitescope monitor?

Tags: oracle11g, db2, sitescope

We have 2 databases. One is an oracle 11g DB and the other is a DB2 database. I need to make a query to the oracle database to get a list of accounts and feed that as parameters into another DB2 query. If the DB2 Query returns any results then I need to send an alert. Is this in any way possible with sitescope (I am fairly new to sitescope so be gentle)? It looks like there is only room for 1 connection string in the sitescope monitors. Can I create 2 monitors (one for DB2 and one for Oracle) and use the results of one query as a parameter into the other monitor? Looks like there is some monitor to monitor capabilities but still trying to understand what is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to extract the results from the first query using a custom script alert, but it is not possible than to reuse the data in another monitor.

SiteScope (SiS) Database Query monitor has no feature to include dynamically changing data in the query used. Generally speaking monitor configurations are static and can only be updated by an external agent (user or integration).

Thinking inside the box of one vendor using HP Operations Orchestration (OO) would be an option to achieve your goal. You could either use OO to run the checks and send you alerts in case of a problem or run the checks and dump the result to a file somewhere which than subsequently can be read by SiS using Script monitor or Logfile monitor.